# Logcat keep scrolling and never stops

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

As soon as I open the android studio its logcat keeps scrolling and never stops with/without executing the project on both physical device and emulator.
Here is what I tried:

1. Invalidate Caches and Restart
2. Clean Project
3. Rebuild
4. Created a new empty project
5. Cell phone driver is working

Link to image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxVPP.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Logcat trackes each and every event that occured in the application say it's the touch event to every other so due to a lot of items logcat always scrolls and the new items will be shown at the bottom. To track a particular event search for the word you added as a key for you log

Comment: yes, you are correct but at some point, it stops right but my logcat never does that. its been 20 min now and it's still running.

Comment: As I explained in my previous comment. The logcat is always moving even no device is connected and other cause the old logs are displayed in the logcat console. So, as this isn't a problem. If you want a detailed tracking of logs head over to the **run** when you app is running here you'll find the logs you manually added and so important logs system throws.

Answer (score 1):

There is no filter active and since the device is running you see the logs of all processes.

Comment: yes but my device's screen is locked and not running any process not even in the background and yet logcat keeps scrolling.

Comment: "not running any process": Well, the logcat output proves the contrary.

Comment: yes that is the problem, even same happen for the emulator

Comment: No, that's not a problem. This is normal. There are always lots of things going on in the device e.g. mobile network activity, wifi, bluetooth, location service, ...